# I need to log hangfire to a different SQL table than nlog

Tags: c#, sql-server, backgroundworker, hangfire

We have nlog saving all logs to a specific database table. Hangfire is automatically logging to the same table. My manager wants the two logs separated; nlog in one table and hangfire in another. I'm completely new to hangfire and I was hoping someone might have a suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest a read through [the documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html) that shows how to define the name of the database in the UseSQLStorage method when adding hangfire.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using ASP.NET Core, in the `Startup` class you can specify the exact storage for all `Hangfire` tables:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseXXXStorage());
}
```

The way how to implement custom logger you can also look into [hangfire-docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html)

Comment: Inside `SqlServerStorageOptions`, you can configure `SchemaName`. Also you can specify the log provider you want to use for your hanfire logs with the following config line .`UseLogProvider`. So here you can provide another log provider (your custom one) and the logs should be stored in different table. Do not forget to also include your custom log into global configuration by `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseLogProvider(new CustomLogProvider());`

Comment: So basically, to solve your issue, you can provide a different log provider specifically for the `Hangfire` logs. There should not be any problems to configure `Hangfire` specific log provider to log into another db table.